# This html code is making me crazy

Tags: javascript, html

```
<html>
<head>
<title>DIsplaying triangle /square</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
document.write("<html><body><p style='line-height:100%;>");
var sides=prompt("Enter the number of sides","3/4");
if(sides==4)
{
    var i=0;

    var j=0;
    var z=0;
    while(i<=6)
    {   
        if(i==0||i==6)
        {
            while(j<=6)
            {
                document.write("*");    
                document.write("<span style='visibility:hidden'>*</span>");
                ++j;
            }
            j=0;
            document.write("<br\>");
        }
        else 
        {
            while(z<=6)
            {
                if(z==0||z==6)
                {
                    document.write("*");
                    document.write("<span style='visibility:hidden'>*</span>");
                }
                else
                {
                    document.write("<span style='visibility:hidden'>*</span>");
                    document.write("<span style='visibility:hidden'>*</span>");
                }
                ++z;
            }
            z=0;
            document.write("<br\>");
        }
        ++i;
    }
    document.write("</p></body></html>");
}
else
{
    var i=0;
}
</script>
</head>
</html>
```

The output when I enter `4` in the prompt box is supposed to be:

```
* * * * * * *
* * * * * * *
* * * * * * *
* * * * * * *
* * * * * * *
* * * * * * *
* * * * * * *
```

(Consider it a perfect square. Its tough to draw it here.)

but I get:

```
** * * * * *
* * * * * * *
* * * * * * *
* * * * * * *
* * * * * * *
* * * * * * *
* * * * * * *
```

Look at the first line. It has first 2 "*"s together. As per the code it is not supposed to happen. Something is going wrong in the `document.write("*")` part. When I tried debugging using `alert` what I found out is that the first time (i.e when i=0) the first `document.write("*")` gets ignored. But every other time it is considered.

Comment: The only thing I could say is: Don't use `document.write`.

Comment: Why???Is whats wrong with it??

Comment: `document.write("<html><body>…` **inside** *`<head>` must* lead to invalid markup. Have a look at your DOM inspector to see what went wrong.

Comment: @Nikhil See [Why is document.write considered a 'bad practice'?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice)

Comment: oh...kk...What is the spacing between 2 lines by default??

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: http://jsbin.com/efehiv/1/edit

This line looks bad to me:

```
document.write("<html><body><p style='line-height:100%;>");
```

Comment: If i remove that line , the spacing between the lines changes and it does not give a perfect square. Thats y i put that line and made line-height:100% which is 100% of the font size(i.e equal to font size..)

Answer (score 0):

Nikhil, you haven't closed your style...begins with single quote and ends with semicolon.  Rewrite to

```
document.write("<html><body><p style=\"line-height:100%;\">");
```

If you feel the paragraph tag is necessary, that's how you can retain it, but it is not necessary.  It is currently messing up the rest of your page though.